# How can I generate classes from XSD that includes another XSD

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have 2 projects:

```
xsdproject/
   src/main/resources/
      a.xsd
      b.xsd

implproject/
```

In implproject I want to generate classes from xsd using maven-jaxb2-plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <cleanPackageDirectories>true</cleanPackageDirectories>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <dependencyResource>
                            <groupId>some.group</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xsdproject</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <resource>a.xsd</resource>
                        </dependencyResource>
                    </schema>
                    <schema>
                        <dependencyResource>
                            <groupId>some.group</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xsdproject</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <resource>b.xsd</resource>
                        </dependencyResource>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The problem comes here -> b.xsd has

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="a.xsd" />
```

and during generation I have an error:

```
 Failed to read schema document 'a.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Is there a way to succesfully import 2 XSD and compile them?

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer.** I am the author of the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Try the following:

`src/main/resources/catalog.cat`:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "a.xsd" "maven:some.group:xsdproject:jar::!/a.xsd"
```

In the `configuration` in `pom.xml`

```
<catalog>src/main/resource/catalog.cat</catalog>
```

(See [Using Catalogs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs).)

I also think you only need to compile `b.xsd`. `a.xsd` should be included automatically.

In case of problems run `mvn -X clean install` and check the log.

See also:

- [Modular Schema Compilation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Modular-Schema-Compilation)
- [ogc-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) - this project does more or less the same thing. The [schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/tree/master/schemas) module only packages schemas and other modules (like, for instance [owc/0.3.1](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/tree/master/owc/0.3.1)) compile these schemas out of the [schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/tree/master/schemas) package. This works with imports and inclusion in any case.

If you need further support, please [file an issue](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues) and provide a sample project.